# configure unattended-upgrades with override.conf

Tags: systemd, unattended-upgrades

Can I configure reboot for unattended-upgrades with override.conf?

Instead of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` I put
`Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";` in `/etc/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service.d/override.conf`. But the syntax is different and I'm not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apt/apt.conf` is just systemd configuration. For apt configuration use for example `51unattended-upgrades` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

Comment: Could you explain your answer some more? Your question was about override.conf. There was no mention of this in the answer.